# UIView in tableViewCell disappearing

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a `tableview` that consists of custom `tableview cells` each with a `UIView` at the center.  My `tableview` has an `array` that consists of dictionaries each with an `AVAsset` and some other data.  The `UIView` within my `tableView cell` is a custom class that draws a waveform of the assets.  I can get the waveform to display, but every time I add a new asset to the array and go to the `tableview`, the `UIView` in the previous row disappears, leaving only the new waveform in the latest row.  Can't figure out why this is happening.

Table View methods:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"audioTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
    OSAudioTableCell *cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    //Dictionary with data
    NSDictionary * packageInArray = [self.audioTableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.userName.text = [packageInArray objectForKey:@"userName"];
    cell.profilePicture.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[packageInArray objectForKey:@"profileImageData"]];

    //UIView related
    [cell setProgress:0]; //This sets timer to 0
    [cell setAsset:[packageInArray objectForKey:@"asset"]];  //This sets the asset
    [cell.waveView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    //NON related to UIView
    CALayer *imageLayer = cell.profilePicture.layer;
    [imageLayer setCornerRadius:20];
    imageLayer.borderColor = (__bridge CGColorRef)([UIColor grayColor]);
    [imageLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];    

    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //When row is selected, the color of the UIView changes, this requires progress and the asset to be set again
    NSDictionary * packageInArray = [self.audioTableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //UIView related
    [((OSAudioTableCell*)[audioTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]) setProgress:0];
    [((OSAudioTableCell*)[audioTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]) setAsset:[packageInArray objectForKey:@"asset"]];
    [((OSAudioTableCell*)[audioTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]) rowSelected:[packageInArray objectForKey:@"audioData"]];

}
```

TableView Cell methods:

```
//Custom method that is called when the row is selected and commands audio player to play
-(void) rowSelected: (NSData*) data
{

    [[OSTablePlayerController getInstance] playAudio:data];

    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.0001 target:self selector:@selector(updateProgress:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

//monitors the progress of the player and draws the different colored UIView
- (void)updateProgress:(NSTimer *)timer {


    NSTimeInterval playTime = [[OSTablePlayerController getInstance] currentTime];
    NSTimeInterval duration = [[OSTablePlayerController getInstance] duration];


    float progress = playTime/duration;    

    //Draws new UIView based on progress
    [self.waveView setProgress:progress];

    if(!([OSTablePlayerController getInstance].player.playing))
    {
        [self audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:[OSTablePlayerController getInstance].player successfully:YES];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The number of rows may not be updating.  Did you try

```
[yourTableView reloadData];
```

After you add new data to the array?

Comment: Ya.  I reload my tableView in the `viewDidLoad` method in my tableView controller.  Do I need to apply this anywhere else?  The number of rows displayed is accurate.  Its just the UIViews fail to load in all rows except the latest row.

Comment: You should call it any time you add, remove, or change items in your datasource.

Comment: @JonBrooks Whenever a new item is added to the array, I automatically popRootViewController to my view controller which holds the tableView.  Since my reloadData method is in viewDidLoad, I think i'm getting the correct value for number of rows based on the array count.

Comment: @Brosef, viewDidLoad is only called once in the life of a view controller. If you're popping back to a controller, viewDidLoad will not be called. You should probably use viewDidAppear instead.