# UIView in tableview cell not working properly

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a tableview that receives an array which consists of dictionaries.  Each dictionary has an AVAsset along with audio data.  I have a UIView in each custom tableview cell that displays the waveform of the `AVAsset` and plays the audio data when the specific cell is selected.  The tableview works perfectly every time I add a dictionary to the array using addObject.  However, I want the newest dictionary to be at the top of the tableView so I'm using `insertObject:AtIndex:0`, but for some reason the `UIView` of the first dictionary added to the array stays in the top cell, and the other UIViews do not load at all.  However, each audio data is in its correct cell.  So if I have three dictionaries in the array, only the `UIView` of the first dictionary is displayed in the top cell with two empty cells below it.  The weird part is the audio data for each dictionary is associated with the correct cell.  Super confusing, but I'm pretty sure this has to do with how the `UIView` of the tableview cell responds when the tableview is reloaded.  Randomly, I can get the second UIView to appear, but its not consistent.  Sorry if this gives you a headache!

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString* word = @"audioTableCell";

    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"audioTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
    OSAudioTableCell *cell =[self.audioTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:word];
    if(!cell)
    {
        cell= (OSAudioTableCell*)[nib objectAtIndex:0];


        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        //Dictionary from the array
        NSDictionary * packageInArray = [self.audioTableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        //Not related to UIView
        cell.userName.text = [packageInArray objectForKey:@"userName"];
        cell.profilePicture.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[packageInArray objectForKey:@"profileImageData"]];


        //This is for the UIView
        [cell setProgress:0];
        [cell setAsset:[packageInArray objectForKey:@"asset"]];
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [cell.waveView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

        //Not related to UIView
        CALayer *imageLayer = cell.profilePicture.layer;
        [imageLayer setCornerRadius:20];
        imageLayer.borderColor = (__bridge CGColorRef)([UIColor grayColor]);
        [imageLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    }


    return cell;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    [arrayStatusLabel setHidden:YES];

    self.primaryUser = [OSPrimaryUser getUserInstance];
    self.primaryUser.userAudioArray = [self.primaryUser createAudioArray];

    self.audioTableArray = self.primaryUser.userAudioArray;

    [self.audioTable registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"audioTableCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"audioTableCell"];


    if([self.audioTableArray count] == 0)
    {
        [self.audioTable setHidden:YES];
         [arrayStatusLabel setHidden:NO];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.audioTable setHidden:NO];
        [arrayStatusLabel setHidden:YES];

    }

    [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];

    [self.audioTable setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];

    [self.audioTable reloadData];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self.audioTable reloadData];

    if([self.audioTableArray count] == 0)
    {
        [self.audioTable setHidden:YES];
        [arrayStatusLabel setHidden:NO];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.audioTable setHidden:NO];
        [arrayStatusLabel setHidden:YES];

    }
}

-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [self.audioTable reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Post your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method (by updating your question).

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIView in tableViewCell disappearing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23668084/uiview-in-tableviewcell-disappearing)

Comment: @JonBrooks this is a separate issue than that initial post you refer to.

Comment: rdelmar is right in his answer below. You can use the register statement in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, but you should assign values outside the `(!cell)` block, so that for each cell gets values. The `(!cell)` block is executed only once, when there is no cell to dequeue. Once it is created, dequeue statement will always return a cell, and the values will not get assigned.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your adding all the data to the cell inside an if (!cell) clause. Best practice would be to register your nib in viewDidLoad (using registerNib:forIdentifier:) instead of loading the nib manually.You will be guaranteed to get a cell this way, and you can eliminate the if (! cell) clause all together. The last bit of code concerning the CALayer doesn't need to run every time the cellForRowAtIndexPath: method is called, so I would move that code to the cell's init method.

**After Edit:**

```
-(void)viwDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"OSAudioTableCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"audioTableCell"];
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString* word = @"audioTableCell";
    OSAudioTableCell *cell =[self.audioTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:word];
   // configure your cell
   return cell;
```

}

As long as you use the same identifier, "audioTableCell", in cellForRowAtIndexPath, you will be guaranteed to get a valid cell.

Comment: How would I then associate that nib in my cellForRowAtIndexPath method?  Not really sure what you mean.

Comment: @Brosef, its associated by the identifier. I've updated my answer with the code.

Comment: besides getting rid of (!cell) does everything else remain the same in cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: @Brosef, you get rid of the nib loading line also.

Comment: I got rid of
`NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"audioTableCell" owner:self options:nil];`
but i left this in
`OSAudioTableCell *cell =[self.audioTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:word];`
Unfortunately I got an error saying "Could not load NIB in bundle:"

Comment: Your code matches mine.  I keep getting this
"*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/user/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/03EF243B-DCA2-4360-A7C8-B89578F92E84/some.app> (loaded)' with name 'OSAudioTableCell''"

Comment: For `[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"OSAudioTableCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"audioTableCell"];`
Should the nib name be "OSAudioTableCell" or the actual name of my xib file which is "audioTableCell.xib"

Comment: I changed nibWithNibName to the name of my xib file and its some what working.  I can get the UIView of the most recently added dictionary to appear, but all the earlier ones are blank.

Comment: @Brosef, hmm... so I guess the problem was not putting everything in the if (!cell) clause. You're going to have to post some more code from your table view controller for anyone to figure this out. I don't see anything in what you've provided so far that could cause this problem.

Comment: I added my viewDidLoad, viewDidAppear, and viewWillAppear methods.  Thats all thats left besides didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: @Brosef, I'm still not seeing anything that could cause this problem, especially if you're seeing "random" behavior. If you want me to take a look at the project, you could email it to me or upload it somewhere so I could download it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53847/discussion-between-brosef-and-rdelmar)

Comment: rdelmar, I believe your answer is a good one, but it is mildly confusing in that it does not make clear that you are solving 2 different problems.  Problem #1: correct use of loading the cell from a nib file.  Problem #2: initializing the cell contents in the wrong place.  The code you present solves problem #1.  See my answer below for discussion about problem #2.

Comment: It seems likely that the "random" behaviour is that he's displaying re-used cell data, and not re-setting the cell content after dequeueing

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as if, during the times when you **do** receive an object back from dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier, you just re-use that cell, without ever updating the values inside it.

That is, you have:

```
OSAudioTableCell *cell =[self.audioTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:word];
if (!cell)
{
    // create a cell ...snip

    // set all the cell content ...snip
}

// You probably want to set the cell content...
// ...out here, instead.

return cell;
```

The way it's written in your question (I assume you copy/pasted from your project), each re-used cell will just display whatever information it had the previous time.

**Added in edit:** It's important to understand that, when you create a table with 100 rows, iOS does =not= allocate 100 cells, one for each row.  Instead, it allocates only enough cells for what fits on the screen -- maybe 7 or 8, depending on the height of your table and your rows -- then, when one cell scrolls off the screen, it is put into a queue to be reused the next time you call dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:

Hence, the 2nd time you get a cell, the view already contains all of the subviews that you initialized the previous time.

`rdelmar`'s answer shows how to correctly create a nib-based cell.  The important thing is: you fill the cell's contents *after* you have a valid cell, as opposed to only when you create it, which is what your code-snippet shows.  Remember: the cell for row #17 might be a recycled cell that was used for row #3.

All of the cell content views -- those that display the waveform, the progress bar, images, or whatever else you have in the cell -- the values and/or content for those need to be set **after** you verify that you have a valid cell and **after** you verify that you have valid views.

For non-nib-based cells, it usually looks something like this (typed in browser; may require tweaking):

```
OSAudioTableCell *cell =[self.audioTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:word];
if (cell == nil)
{
    // create a cell
    [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier];
}

UILabel *cellLabel = [cell viewWithTag: kMyLabelTag];
if (myLabel == nil)
{
    cellLabel = [UILabel new];
    cellLabel = kMyLabelTag;
    // set-up frame, whatever else...
    [cell addSubView: cellLabel];
}
cellLabel = someGoodText;  // NOTE: we do this whether the field is new or old!

SpecialView *cellView = [cell viewWithTag: kMyViewTag];
if (cellView == nil)
{
    cellView = [SpecialView new];
    cellView = kMyViewTag;
    // set-up frame, whatever else...
    [cell addSubView: cellView];
}
cellView.specialField = someValue;  // NOTE: we do this whether the field is new or old!

// etc., repeat for other cell-content.

return cell;
```

For your nib-based cells, the various sub-views are loaded from the nib, so you can assume they exist and skip the `if (cellSubView == nil) createCelLSubview` part.

Hope that helps!